# How can I arrange the alphabet into homotopy equivalence classes?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I have sorted the alphabet into homeomorphism equivalence classes intuitively using that homeomorphisms only allow bending, twisting, and no cuts. Now I'm asked to sort it into homotopy equivalence classes but I'm not sure how to do this intuitively. I know that two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if there exist maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g\simeq Id_X$ and $g\circ f\simeq Id_Y$ but I don't think I can use that here, so what's the intuition behind homotopy equivalence?

I know that the answer is

[image]

Comment: I think, here, the point is when you add 'sticks' to your space it doesn't change the homotopy type

Comment: Intuitively, the question here is simply about how many "holes" each shape has.  Each of $A,R,D,O,P,Q$ have one hole.  $B$ has two holes, and each of the rest have no holes.  As you extend to higher dimensions, then you can have holes of different types... two-dimensional holes, three-dimensional holes, etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense. How does that relate to the definition? i.e if I didn't know the answer, how could I get to it?

Comment: See [this animation of a coffee cup being deformed into a donut and vice versa](https://www.reddit.com/r/visualizedmath/comments/86o47u/a_donut_is_topologically_equivalent_to_a_coffee/).  Similarly, you can see that $A$ can be deformed to look like $R$ just by a slight rotation and then bending right pen-stroke some in two places.  Further, $R$ is able to be deformed to $P$ by taking the right leg and making it shorter and shorter until it retracted into the rest of the letter, thereby effectively being removed.

Comment: The point being, when retracting you can't "*plug any holes*"  (*a circle $\circ$ is not homotopically equivalent to a point $\cdot$*), you cant make any new holes (*vice versa of the previous example*), you can't "cut" which effectively removed a hole (*$O$ to $U$*), or connect previously unconnected (*$U$ to $O$*), and so on...